# Render data from JSON in react native

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native, arraylist

im trying to render these JSON data but I cant access company at all.I cant figure out where is the problem? This is the JSON:

```
[
{
   "address": {
       "country": "Albania",
       "city": "Tirana",
       "street": "Sheshi Skenderbe"
   },
   "_id": "5fc96784e740aaa9af2139ae",
   "company": "Big market",
   "phone": "+35568123456"
}
]
```

This is my code:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axiosApiInstance.get(`/companies/list/1`);
        setData(response.data);
        console.log(response.data, "Data from Furnitoret");
      } catch (err) {
        Alert.alert("Mesazhi", err.response.data.message);
      }
    })();
  }, []);
```

and the render

```
 <FlatList
        keyExtractor={(item, i) => i.toString()}
        data={data}
        renderItem={({ item, i }) => (
          <Card
            title={data.company}
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Porosia")}
          />
        )}
      />
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `title={item.company}`?

Answer (score 0):

Within your renderItem prop of the flatlist, you giving the name `item` to each element in the `data` array, but then you are trying to use your data object which is the complete list, instead of the current `item`.

It should be

```
      <FlatList
        keyExtractor={(item, i) => item._id}
        data={data}
        renderItem={({ item, i }) => (
          <Card
            title={item.company} // <----------------- item not data
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Porosia")}
          />
        )}
      />
```

Also, as a side note you might want to use the company id as the key instead of the array index, as you might run into performance problems when updating this list later on

```
keyExtractor={(item, i) => item._id}
```

Comment: Thank you, now is okay

Comment: @Emily when someone solves your problem on StackOverflow you should mark their answer as the correct answer. This is the way of saying thank you and gives them reputation points making it worth their time to answer.

Comment: I know but i dont have the reputation to do it

Comment: @Emily You sure can. You don't need reputation to accept an answer. Check next to answers there is a greyed out check mark. Click it to accept an answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

change `data.company` to `item.company` like

```
<Card
    title={item.company}
/>
```